# In case of failure in the Electronic Flight Instrument System, how would they be transferred between each other?

Tags: avionics, electronics, display

In EFIS, in case of failure in the PFD, where would be PFD shown? In case of failure in the ND, where it would be shown? In case the PFD & ND both fail, where would they be shown?

[image]

Comment: The pilot and copilot PFD's are separate systems, if the pilots PFD fails, the copilot PFD should still be operational. The screens can be switched on either side but if they both failed for some reason the pilot with working displays will probably assume control.

Comment: Are you asking about failure of the display itself?

Comment: Yes, I am asking about in case of one or two of these displays fail what is the situation ?!

Comment: I've seen document on captainpilot.com, which described this for A320 too, but the site is down.

Answer (score 15):

On the Embraer 170/190-series, the normal display layout is as follows:

[image]

There is an automatic display reversion logic when one or more panels fail. The following image shows this logic:
[image]

There is also a manual reversion switch located near each pilot's outboard knee, which controls what is displayed on the panel:

[image: ![enter image description here]

All images sourced from an Embraer Airplane Operations Manual.

Comment: What will the MFD contains in case of failure ? and can you label the priority of the displays from the Most significant until the Less significant displays ?

Comment: A failed display will be blank. As you can see by the system logic that the PFD is given the highest priority, then the EICAS, and finally the MFD.